# Cookie expires after a couple of mins? Timeout not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, forms-authentication, session-cookies, session-timeout

I have code like this in Login Controller. I create a cookie and sessions when the user login with the correct username and password.

```
Models.DTO.Security.CustomPrincipalSerializeModel serializeModel = new Models.DTO.Security.CustomPrincipalSerializeModel();
serializeModel.Id = member.Id;
serializeModel.UserName = member.UserName;
serializeModel.RoleId = member.RoleId;
serializeModel.IsAdmin = member.IsAdmin;

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string userData = serializer.Serialize(serializeModel);
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
    1,
    model.UserName,
    DateTime.Now,
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),
    false,
    userData
    );
string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket)
{
    HttpOnly = true

};
Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);


Session["CartItemsCount"] = 0;

Session["CartItems"] = new List<Models.DTO.CartDTO.CartVM>();

Session["DiscountPercentage"] = member.DiscountPercentage;

Session["CreditLimit"] = member.CreditLimit;
```

And I have the following Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="60"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Index" timeout="60" name=".ASPXAUTH" />
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
```

I set the timeout to expire in 60 minutes in everywhere. Everything seems right. And there is no problem in local server. 
But when I publish this project in server, the system redirecting users to Home/Index(Login Page) after 5 mins of inactivity.

I cannot figure out why. Is there something I am missing?

Could the problem be related to Machine Key? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using machine key.

I generate a machine key and I added it to web.config.

[for generate machine key](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Resources/MachineKey.aspx)

Final version of my web config file

```
 <system.web>
        <machineKey 
validationKey="5DEBFB5B7BA6F3E1DB190A2BF28F08AEB8964618C2895BD931A735143D1A9C61DA59443F8B407F125447A663452F76AB82F18E4191911E3D563700CD4CA27138"
decryptionKey="A0048282BE5B72D6028F46820C87A360906430E9E3D8EDE09BAB79E95AF4B9A2"
validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"
/>
        <sessionState timeout="60"/>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Index" timeout="60" name=".ASPXAUTH" />
        </authentication>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <httpModules>
          <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
        </httpModules>
      </system.web>
```